# Is there any way to trigger component method from parent in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have been searching for information and have only found a way to emit events from child components which can be then listened for in parent components. Is there any way to call a child method from parent component?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Yup, just find your component in children array, or grab it by ref attribute, and call method :)
[ref doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

lets assume that your child component has method x.
According to documentation:

```
<div id="parent">
  <user-profile ref="profile"></user-profile>
</div>

var child = this.$refs.profile;
child.x();
```

Comment: Same here "cannot read property "profile" of undefined".
ref attribute works for native elements, but it's not working on custom components.

Comment: just to be clear: components under $refs property are available after correspondings components have been created (i thought it is obvious :) ), so you can use it in the mounted handler for example.

Comment: This is a bad practice, because it breaks recommend data and events flow in components.

Comment: But what if you're using a third-party component and does not have any exposed API? It may be bad practice but sometimes you don't have a choice...

Comment: I agree with @zedee: it's very useful when wrapping third-party components. I'm replacing a new library with an old one and creating a custom wrapper lets me avoid repetition, but this wouldn't be possible without calling the methods from the parent.

Answer (score 28):

I think a good pattern for this is emitting an event from the parent component and listening to it in the child component, using an [Event Bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

That would be:

**in main.js**

```
export const bus = new Vue()
```

**in Parent.vue:**

```
import {bus} from 'path/to/main'

// Where you wanna call the child's method:
bus.$emit('customEventName', optionalParameter)
```

**in Child.vue:**

```
import {bus} from 'path/to/main'

// Add this to the mounted() method in your component options object:
bus.$on('customEventName', this.methodYouWannaCall)
```

Comment: could you elaborate, please? I don't understand what we're doing here and why.

Comment: @tatsu It creates an extra Vue instance and uses the methods provided by the Vue instance to implement an event bus.

Comment: simply pass ref attribute to the component and use it to call its methods `<component ref="componentRef"> ... this.$refs.componentRef.theMethod()`

Comment: The link to your "Event Bus" documentation provided is broken and the concept seems to be discontinued in favor of vuex.

Comment: See also: https://tkacz.pro/vue-js-why-event-bus-is-bad-idea/