# this.$emit throws TypeError

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm creating a small  vue3 component and need to emit an event on a method call.

This is roughly how it looks **:**

```
export default {
  emits: ['event'],
  methods: {
    myMethod () {
      this.$emit('event') // throws Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$emit('event') //works perfectly fine
  }
}
```

Can someone help me in finding what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When are you calling "myMethod"?

Comment: Can you share your full component code? Are you using composition api or options api?

Comment: There is no flaw in you code (in what we can see). Please upload your component entirely, and where you use the component, and also when you fire `myMethod`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys from comments, got me thinking in another way

I am just started learning Vue, and so the problem is pretty stupid

How I was calling the method from the parent component:

```js
childComponent.methods.myMethod()
```

So I realized I was doing something wrong and after a couple of minutes of googling found the solution in the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494001/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-component-method-from-parent-in-vuejs)